# Nesting blocks? Adding text at the bottom of a block

Tags: css, block

I need to add a few words at the bottom of a block.  .label is the block.  Inside is a .label_title, and under that is picture/ link that is a block also.  Under  the picture/link a need to a brief description, but I want it to stay in the .label block.  I tried to use

the .label   but it didn’t show.  I’m not sure if that’s because of the css or if I can’t nest a block(

) inside of a block(.label) underneath a block (.label_seo1_1).  Sorry if this is confusing I don’t know how to put it.  Basically I want to add a paragraph on the bottom of the .label block under the .label_seo1_1.     I pasted the css code and html that I am currently using.

Attempt at a graphical depiction.

```
*********.label*********************
*    .label_tile                   *
*   **Link/picture(block**         *  
*   ****************               *
*      ****Want to add text****    *
************************************


 .label {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 160px;
height: 200px;
}

 .label_title {

font-size: 12px;
line-height: 14px;
height: 15px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
}


 .label_seo1_1{
width: 150px;
height: 155px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

 .label_seo1_1 {
background: url('images/label_seo1_1.png') no-repeat;   
}





 <div class="label">
<div class="label_title">6000 Blog Comments</div>
      <a class="label_seo1_1" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/6000-blog-           comments/' ) ); ?>"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: like this - http://jsfiddle.net/elen/Hrx2C/ ?

Comment: yes just like that accept I don't want the border.  I'm gonna try it

Comment: i've added border for visual representation only...

Comment: Now how do I mark this question answered.  Thanks for everything is works perfect.  I been trying to do that for days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vertical align property for .label

```
vertical-align:text-bottom;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elen/Hrx2C)

Comment: Another question.  .Label_title is runnuing on to the Label_seo1.  Any idea how I can seperate them a little more

Comment: @user1792478 yes, use margin property, i.e. margin-bottom: 2px; - jsfiddle.net/elen/Hrx2C/2